# How to iterate over uploaded files in Grails

Tags: java, grails, file-upload, groovy

I have this GSP:

```
<g:uploadForm name="myForm" action='save'>    
    <input type='file' name='documentFile' value=''/>
    <input type='file' name='documentFile' value=''/>
    <input type='file' name='documentFile' value=''/>
    <input type='file' name='documentFile' value=''/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</g:uploadForm>
```

But when I tried to view the result in controller by typing:

```
render(params);
return true;
```

I got this result:

```
"documentFile":org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@14dcf95
```

How do I read each file that is being uploaded? 
Could I get the following?

```
documentFile:[File,null,File,null] // (if the 2nd and the 4th are not being used)
```

ps: I'm using grails 1.2.2

Comment: Do you have a variable number of files in your form, or will it always be four? If it's variable, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: it's variable. I did add number at the end of name ... but it still weird because when you type <input type='text' name='something'/> many times it will produce array of "something" in params.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking through the Grails API and couldn't find a method that retrieves a File[] object based on file inputs. The Servlet API provides the method for grabbing the String[] array, but I haven't looked at its source to see how it does it. Presumably it could be done with some manual work on the HTTP request, but that's probably too much work. Using Grails' `request.fileNames` is probably a reasonable equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you'll need to give unique names to each of your file inputs:

```
<g:uploadForm name="myForm" action="save">
    <input type="file" name="documentFile1" value=""/>
    <input type="file" name="documentFile2" value=""/>
    ...
</g:uploadForm>
```

Then in your controller, you can use:

```
// access each file by name
File file = request.getFile('documentFile1')

// or iterate through them
request.fileNames.each {
    File file = request.getFile(it)
}
```

I'm pretty sure that your `name` attributes have to be unique. I can't find anything in the API that will allow you to get an array of files that were uploaded with the same input `name`.

References:

- http://www.grails.org/File+Upload
- http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.9%20Uploading%20Files

Comment: A year later and this solution was still helpful.  Thanks Rob!

Comment: So I can't use `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />`?

Comment: I don't believe so. I mean, you can, but it won't work exactly like PHP. You'll still be able to iterate over `fileNames` to accomplish essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with grails 1.2 (spring 3.0), you can access multiple files from inputs with the same name (or that use the HTML5 `multiple` attribute) with the `multiFileMap` property of the controller's `request` object (when the request is a multipart form post, the `request` object will be an instance of [MultipartRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartRequest.html)). So you can access the list of [MultipartFile](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) objects for a specific input name (ie `documentFile`) like this:

```
def save = {
    List<MultipartFile> files = request.multiFileMap.documentFile
    int count = files.findAll { !it.empty }.size
    render "uploaded $count files"
}
```

Or access all MultipartFile objects from all inputs like this:

```
def save = {
    List<MultipartFile> files = request.multiFileMap.collect { it.value }.flatten()
    int count = files.findAll { !it.empty }.size
    render "uploaded $count files"
}
```

---

Edit 2013-02-08: [Brian Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329643/bryan-adams) asks:

> In above case, I can access all MultipartFile objects from all inputs
>   on my web page. But I wants to get files from any input is multiple.
>   Ex: I have input name is: "uploadFiles", and I wants get all files
>   from this input tag any. Can you help me?

Brian, I think what you want is the first version of the above. If your file input is named "uploadFiles", then you can access it from the multiFileMap using the "uploadFiles" key:

```
def save = {
    List<MultipartFile> files = request.multiFileMap.uploadFiles
    int count = files.findAll { !it.empty }.size
    render "uploaded $count files"
}
```