# how to upload multiple files in grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

I have a form that contains multi file upload like this one

```
<g:form name="legalActionForm" controller="legalAction" action="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='documentFile'/> <input type='text' name='documentDate'/>
<input type='file' name='documentFile'/> <input type='text' name='documentDate'/>
<input type='file' name='documentFile'/> <input type='text' name='documentDate'/>
<input type='file' name='documentFile'/> <input type='text' name='documentDate'/>
<input type='file' name='documentFile'/> <input type='text' name='documentDate'/>
<input type='submit' value='update'/>
</g:form>
```

user can add more if needed ... 
how to get each file using iterators ?

if only one file I use `request.getFile('documentFile');`
but if I tried with `request.getFileNames().each{obj -> println("${obj}"); }`  I only got the first one ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over uploaded files in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710232/how-to-iterate-over-uploaded-files-in-grails)

Comment: The reason you only received the first 'documentFile' when using `request.fileNames.each {}` is because your names are not unique in your form. Jinesh's answer fixes this; I also addressed this when you asked this question a couple months ago.

Comment: @nightingale2k1 new answer added

Answer (score 9):

```
request.getMultiFileMap().documentFile.each {
    println it.originalFilename
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution when using the multiple attribute of the input tag.

Answer (score 5):

You want to do it like so

```
   <g:form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >  
   <input type='file' name='documentFile.1' />  
   <input type='file' name='documentFile.2' />  
   <input type='file' name='documentFile.3' />  
   </g:form>
```

In your controller

```
def files = []  
params.documentFile.each {  
  files.add(it.value)  
 }
```

Comment: When I use the multiple attribute I can't get it to work. `<input type="file" id="files" name="arquivos[]" multiple />`

Answer (score 3):

You try with this one

```
request.fileNames.each {
   MultipartFile file = request.getFile(it)
   //File file = request.getFile(it)
   //do what you want
}
```